# ClearCase - find all the files that are viewed on a certain branch

Tags: unix, clearcase

In ClearCase, I would like to see a list of all the files that I am viewing on a certain branch (if I have branch `Br` I would like a list of all the files that I am viewing a version of them in that branch). Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use...

cleartool find . -all -nvisible -element 'brtype(Br)' -print %CLEARCASE_PN%

The above is supposed to find all elements (even invisible to this view) with the branch BR, and print the pathnames.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to:

- create a dynamic view
- set the right config spec with the relevant element selection rules you want in order to list all the right files.

Don't forget a branch exists independently from files: when you create a branch, no file is affected. Only the file with at least one checked-out version will register in that branch (within their tree view).

See "[How to find a Parent Label of a branch in Clearcase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352609/how-to-find-a-parent-label-of-a-branch-in-clearcase)" for illustration.