# Find elements on branch and with specific label

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

Using `cleartool`, how do I find elements (file or folder):

- on a specific branch
  **and**
- with a specific label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mentioned before how to [search elements by label](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2221254/6309).

You should be able to add a `brtype` selector ([as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4011822/6309)) to restrict to a given branch:

Unix:

```
cleartool find -all -element '{lbtype_sub(REL1) && brtype(BRANCHNAME)}' -print
```

Windows:

```
cleartool find -all -element "{lbtype_sub(REL1) && brtype(BRANCHNAME)}" -print
```